# Where is all "com.android.camera. - - -" intent filter actions are defined?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I do use of "com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" but for the video I am searching for similar thing ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of hardcoding that String value you should use `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, if you mean "similar thing" you can look for other values inside the class MediaStore.

Comment: thanks for that but firstly I tried with MediaStore but I don't know why its not working at that time now its ok